# Display data using Microsoft Report Viewer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reportviewer

I created a windows form with Report Viewer that showing data from SQL database.
What I did so far:
1. I created stored procedure on SQL server that is imported to my program (Entity Framework is used as the object mapper).
2. I created report (.rdlc) with parameter that macthes the parameter in the stored procedure.
3. Finally, I created Report Viewer and chose the report already created.

There is one parameter in the stored procedure and if I pass the value using text box everything works well.
But if I try to pass a value using combo box using "Data Bound Items" Report Viewer shows nothing.
This is an example of code that works (passing value by text box):

```
private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetCustomer_ResultBindingSource.DataSource = db.GetCustomer(txtProductName.Text).ToList();

            ReportParameter[] rParam = new ReportParameter[]
            {
                new ReportParameter("ProductName",txtProductName.Text)
            };

            reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(rParam);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
```

A solution with combobox instead of textbox that doesn't show data in Report Viewer is:

```
    GetCustomer_ResultBindingSource.DataSource = db.GetCustomer(cboProductName.SelectedItem.ToString()).ToList();

    ReportParameter[] rParam = new ReportParameter[]
    {
            new ReportParameter("ProductName",cboProductName.SelectedItem.ToString())
    };

    reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(rParam);
    this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Data source is loaded:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ProductBindingSource.DataSource = db.Products.ToList();
        }
```

Data source, Display Member and Value Member are defined in the options of the combo box (used to fill the combobox).

Any help for the second solution?

Many thanks!

Comment: How fill the combobox?, if you use a datasource, make sure, asign the dysplayMember property and valueMember property, then use combobox.selectedValue

Comment: I already said how the combox is filled (see the initial post).

Comment: then, try assigning valueMember and displayMember, ValueMember is the peroductname column, and when calling use the SelectedValue property, same as in this example: GetCustomer_ResultBindingSource.DataSource = db.GetCustomer (cboProductName.SelectedValue) .ToList ();

Comment: Great this works. Display Member and Value Member are "Product Name".
GetCustomer_ResultBindingSource.DataSource = db.GetCustomer (cboProductName.SelectedValue.ToString()) .ToList ();

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Henoc Salinas and his comment above. This is solved.

This is working solution:

**Display Member** = "Product Name" - value that is passed to SQL query

**Value Member** = "Product Name" (initially I put a primary key column here and it was wrong).

and therefore I called **SelectedValue**.ToString() (instead of SelectedItem.ToString())

The working code is:

```
private void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetCustomer_ResultBindingSource.DataSource = db.GetCustomer(cboProduct.SelectedValue.ToString()).ToList();

            ReportParameter[] rParam = new ReportParameter[]
            {
                new ReportParameter("ProductName", cboProduct.SelectedValue.ToString())
            };

            reportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(rParam);
            reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
```